# Using an iMac as a display for PC laptop in dual mointor configuration

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, target-display, dual-screen

My goal is to have two large monitors for my PC laptop without having to purchase new monitors. My current setup is a late 2013 27” iMac with a 27” Thunderbolt Display. For work I was given a Lenovo T480 which has a Thunderbolt 3 port on it.

I want to know if I’ll be able to use my iMac in Target Display Mode as one Monitor, plus my Thunderbolt Display as the second monitor? I can use the Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter from the laptop to the iMac, but will it recognize the Thunderbolt Display as the second one? It’s about $100 of cables and adapters to try this so I wanted to ask first.

Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

The iMac will connect to a Thunderbolt port. (But no other.) Also, you can't 'daisy-chain' the [iMac in Target Display mode](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/ins-outs-imacs-target-display-mode/) to another monitor.

And the TB Display also can't be daisy-chained, but it can connect to other video ports. So you'll need to use another video out port on the Lenovo, with all the necessary adaptors to get it to the TB's connector.

Comment: I ended up getting the Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter and tried to make this work. The result was that I can use the Thunderbolt out on the T480 into the Apple Thunderbolt Display. To make it work I needed to go into the BIOS to enable Thunderbolt assistance and set the security to “no security”. This makes the Apple Display and usb peripherals all work. As mentioned in the prev answer, Target Display mode doesn’t work on the iMac. I have a 2nd Thunderbolt Display and daisy chaining isn’t working for display but sound does work... any ideas on getting the Display to work?